# How to install a Theos project to device?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I'm new to cydia dev and I downloaded a couple of examples fro iphonedevwiki.
I've got my iPad jailbroken and how do I install the demo Theos tweak to my device? Thanks.

And by the way is iOSOpenDev working for iOS 8?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Once you have compiled your tweak (using `make`), you need to create a deb package file (using `make package`). This will create a `.deb` file. Then you transfer the .deb file to your iPad. Once it is transfered, open an ssh session to it and install it from the command line using:

```
dpkg -i 'filename.deb'
```

Of course, the method Cl3ment mentioned works too but this is a step-by-step way of doing it in case you wanted to do some parts manually.

Answer (score 0):

If your device and your computer use the same Wi-Fi network, you need to edit the project's Makefile to add this to its first line :

```
THEOS_DEVICE_IP = 192.168.1.4
```

(Of course, replace the IP address with your iDevice's IP)

To install the tweak, you need to use the `make package install` command within Terminal. It will compile the tweak, then create a .deb package for it, then attempt to install it to your device (you will be prompted for root password two times, and your iDevice will then respring)

Comment: This is the recommended and the fastest way of doing it. However, I recommend you to use something like iPhoneTunnel to connect to your iDevice using a lightning cable rather than your LAN.